# Clone div based on content of span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are random number of div's as show below, I am trying to clone these div on click. when cloning I want to change the content to actual content + no of clones it has (based on content of span , not the id or classes of "clone-this")

eg.

- If I click the first **"chrome"** div, since the body already have "chrome (1) and  chrome (2)" , div with content **"chrome (3)"** Should appear .
- If I click the 2nd div ie. **"Mozilla Firefox"**, since there is no cloned version, a div with content **"Mozilla Firefox (1)"** should appear.

  and so on.

I tried to make this,  but when i clone the count is based on class , not the content . so clicking on "chrome"  div will clone "chrome (5)" not "chrome (3)" .

Also in my implementation when i click the "chrome (1)" div, it will clone as "chrome (1)(5)" . I want this to be like  "chrome (3)"

how can i achieve this?

note that there will be any number of divs at first. 5 is just for and example.

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jayakrishnancn/ofqd006s/)

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.clone-this', function(){ 
      var CloneContainer = $(this).clone();
      var no = $('.clone-this').size();
      CloneContainer.html(CloneContainer.html() + " (" + no + ")");
      CloneContainer.appendTo('body');
  });
```

```css
.clone-this{
      padding: 15px;
      width: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin: 10px auto;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #444;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-family: monospace;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Chrome</span></div>
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Mozilla Firefox</span></div>
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Safari</span></div>  
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Chrome (1)</span></div>
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Chrome (2)</span></div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to amend the HTML? It would make this a very simple job if you can store the count of the element in a `data` attribute instead of in brackets in the text content. As it is you'll probably need some regex parsing which is just adding avoidable complexity.

Comment: _“but when i clone the count is based on class , not the content”_ - well that’s because you _select_ the elements you count based on their class. You want to select them based on their content instead - so surely you have already done your research on how _that_ can be accomplished …?

Comment: Try `CloneContainer.html( CloneContainer.html() .split('(')[0] + "(" + no + ") );`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i cant change the html , because page is rendering form  server , and i dont have access to change backend, but is there any way to change it from frontend?

Comment: @CBroe yes . i tried with str.match function, i couldnt do it

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: @XYZ Thank you .2nd part of question is solved, but the main problem still remains... https://jsfiddle.net/jayakrishnancn/ofqd006s/4/

Comment: @Jayakrishnan check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jeu6sd0v/

Comment: @XYZ  you see ... the problem is that if u click on "Mozilla Firefox" (initially) it should make the  div with "Mozilla Firefox (1)" on it . In your code the count is same as the total clone number ie. "Mozilla Firefox(5)" .

Comment: @Jayakrishnan have you checked this https://jsfiddle.net/jeu6sd0v/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To accomplish that, you should check "content" of each item and count the number of elements which have same text. But, there is one problem here; each element (for example Chrome, Chrome (1), Chrome (2)) has different content. So, you may split the text using parenthesis or you may use RegEx (recommended).

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.clone-this', function(){ 
  var CloneContainer = $(this).clone();
  var content = CloneContainer.find('span').html().split(' (')[0];
  var no = $(".clone-this:contains('"+content+"')").size();
  
  CloneContainer.html( CloneContainer.html() .split(' (')[0] + " (" + no + ")" );
  CloneContainer.appendTo('body');
});
```

```css
.clone-this{
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clone-this"><span>Chrome</span></div>
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Mozilla Firefox</span></div>
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Safari</span></div>  
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Chrome (1)</span></div>
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Chrome (2)</span></div>
```

On the snippet above, you may see basic version of it. But you MUST consider the "similar content" issue like following.

- Chrome
- Chrome Mobile
- Firefox
- Firefox Mobile

Comment: perfect. Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get you going. I *"trim"* the `clicked` `div` to its **base name** and then loop through the `divs` and get the `length` of all which contain the same **base name**.

After that I modify the cloned element to fill in the right count of the cloned element appropriately:

```js
var regExp = /\([0-9]+\)/;

$('.clone-this').click(function(e){
  var target = e.target.textContent;
  var matches = regExp.exec(target);
  var elements = $('.clone-this');
  var count = elements.length;
  var index = 0;
  
  if (null != matches) {
    target = matches.input.substr(0, matches.input.lastIndexOf(" "));
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    index += (elements[i].textContent.indexOf(target) > -1) ? 1: 0;
  }
  
  var CloneContainer = $(this).clone();
  CloneContainer.html(CloneContainer.html().split('(')[0] + "(" + index + ")" );
  CloneContainer.appendTo('body');
});
```

```css
.clone-this{
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clone-this"><span>Chrome</span></div>
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Mozilla Firefox</span></div>
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Safari</span></div>  
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Chrome (1)</span></div>
  <div class="clone-this"><span>Chrome (2)</span></div>
```